# Is the contract metadata automatically deployed on Swarm?

Tags: contract-deployment, swarm

From the solidity docs on contract metadata:

> You have to publish the metadata file to Swarm (or another service) so that others can access it. You create the file by using the solc --metadata command that generates a file called ContractName_meta.json.

When I use Truffle with an Infura api key, or Remix with MetaMask, does the node publish the contract metadata file on Swarm? Or, if I run my own geth or parity node, does it happen there?

Answer (score 1):

At least in Remix, it seems the answer is no, they don't automatically deploy your contract on Swarm. You can do it manually via the button below.

[image: Remix Screen Capture]